# My SQLite Update statement keeps inserting 0 into the first field and the correct values after that

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am facing a really annoying bug which is that it keeps inputting a `0` into the first column and then the rest of the values after.

This is my code:

```
System.out.println(forename);
String statement = "UPDATE " + USER_TABLE + " SET " + FORENAME + " = " + "'" + forename + "'"
+ " AND " + SURNAME + " = " + "'" + surname + "'" + " AND " + EMAIL + " = " + "'" + email + "'"  
+ "WHERE " + USER_ID + " = " + userID;
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(statement);
```

So if forename was `Luke` it would print `Luke` but then after running this query the table would look like this:

```
UserID  |  Forename   |  Surname   | Email
____________________________________________

1            0           Smith        luke@s.com
```

As you can see `Luke` was not put into the `Forename` field despite the fact that I can clearly see the value `Luke` being printed in `LogCat`

Comment: How are you observing what's in the database?

Comment: Never mind, it has been resolved using the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should use `ContentValues` for this task:

For example:

```
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(FORENAME, forename);
    values.put(SURNAME, surname);
    values.put(EMAIL, email);
    database.update(USER_TABLE, values, USER_ID + "=?", new String[] {userID});
    database.close();
    return true;
```

Comment: Hi, I want to update all the values in the table where `User_ID` = `1` - will this work? So that includes a new `forename`, a new `surname` etc

Comment: The USER_ID + "=?" clause is the 'where' and the new String[] { userID } is what will replace the "?" in the where clause. If userId is a long, you can use  new String[] { Long.toString(userID) } or new String[] { userID + "" }

Comment: Yeah. You can try it. just create a method with 4 parameters you want and just try.
More details: http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: Worked like a CHARM! Thanks mate, you literally made my day :) +1